# Combine three functions in one graph using Plot3D and show

Tags: plotting

I have a function, f, which is divided in three functions depending on the ranges of some variables (`a` and `r`) and constants (`o` and `c`). More specifically, I have:

```
    (2o+c)/3                     if a < ((2o+c)/3)*((o-c)/(3o)) 
f = (2*(1 + r)*o+c)/(3 + 4r)     if a > o/4 
    [(1/2)*(0 + Sqrt[o^2-4oa])]  if a ∈ [((2o+c)/3)*((o-c)/(3o)), o/4] and r > 1/8 Sqrt[(o + 2 c)^2/(o*(o/4 - a))]
```

, where `c` and `o` are constants. I would like to plot `f` as a function of `r` and `a`.

I have tried plotting them individually (assuming `o = 5` and `c = 0`):

```
f1 = Plot3D[10/3, {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
f2 = Plot3D[1/2*(5 + Sqrt[5 - 20*a]), {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
f3 = Plot3D[(2*(1 + r))/(3 + 4*r), {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

and then "merging" them together:

```
Show[f1, f2, f3]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Ideally, the **desired output** should be something like:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow incorporate the ranges inside the function instead of randomly assigning numbers to the constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create the complete function with `If`

```
o = 5; c = 0;
f[r_, a_] = If[a < ((2 o + c)/3)*((o - c)/(3 o)), Evaluate[(2 o + c)/3], 0] + 
            If[a > o/4, Evaluate[(2*(1 + r)*o + c)/(3 + 4 r)], 0] + 
            If[MemberQ[{((2 o + c)/3)*((o - c)/(3 o)), o/4}, a] &&  
                r > 1/8 Sqrt[(o + 2 c)^2/(o*(o/4 - a))], 
                Evaluate[(1/2)*(0 + Sqrt[o^2 - 4 o a])], 0]

Plot3D[f[r, a], {a, 0, 2}, {r, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Notice that I choose the default value to be `0` if no conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Manipulate` to visualize how the plot varies with `o` and `c`. It's easiest to see the different parts if we define them separately:

```
f1[c_, o_][r_, a_] := (2 o + c)/3*
If[a < ((2 o + c)/3)*((o - c)/(3 o)), 1, Null]

f2[c_, o_][r_, a_] := (2*(1 + r)*o + c)/(3 + 4 r)*If[a > o/4, 1, Null]

f3[c_, o_][r_, a_] := Block[{alim1, alim2},
  alim1 = ((2 o + c)/3)*((o - c)/(3 o));
  alim2 = o/4;
  (1/2)*(Sqrt[o^2 - 4 o a])*
  If[Min[alim1, alim2] <= a <= Max[alim1, alim2] && 
    r > 1/8 Sqrt[(o + 2 c)^2/(o*(o/4 - a))], 1, Null
  ]
]
```

The `If` statements ensures that we only plot something when the constraints are satisfied. Now we can use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  {Tooltip[f1[c, o][r, a], "f1"], Tooltip[f2[c, o][r, a], "f2"], 
   Tooltip[f3[c, o][r, a], "f3"]},
  {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}
  , PlotRange -> All
  ]
 , {c, 0, 5}, {o, 0.1, 10}
 ]
```

Giving something like this:
[image: manipulate]

Hovering the mouse pointer over any curve reveals which function it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to use something like regionplot3d,

I am no adept however so ll just throw examples at you

```
RegionPlot3D[ 0 <= z <= 4 - y && 0 <= y <= 4 - x^2, {x, -2, 2},
{y, -1, 5}, {z, 0, 6}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[{Yellow, Opacity[0.4]}], AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

you can also cut away unwanted ranges using RegionFunction

for example.

```
Plot3D[{4 - y, 4 - x^2, 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4.1}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.7]}, {Yellow, Opacity[0.4]}, {Green, 
Opacity[0.4]}}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= z <= Min[4 - x^2, (4 - y)]]]
```

actually not sure I am helping here ^^ (I cant add comments yet)